# R - factor gets converted to character with levels()

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a large dataset with four indicator variables for `wilderness`. I want to collapse those into a single factor variable, with the variable names as levels. When I do this outside of the function below, it works fine. When inside of the function, `wilderness` is converted to class "character".

This works correctly, and `wilderness` is a factor with levels = variable names in `data.frame(fct)`:

```
to_factor = function(var, df){
    for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    var[df[, i] == 1] = i
    }
    factor(var)
}

fct = fct.og[, 1:10]
fct$wilderness = to_factor(fct$wilderness, fct.og[, 11:14])
levels(fct$wilderness) = colnames(fct.og[, 11:14])
```

This turns `wilderness` into class = character in `data.frame(fct)`:

```
to_factor = function(var, df){
    for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    var[df[, i] == 1] = i
    }
    factor(var)
    levels(var) = colnames(df)
}

fct = fct.og[, 1:10]
fct$wilderness = to_factor(fct$wilderness, fct.og[, 11:14])
```

Was hunting for an easily reproducible example, but did not find a base dataset to use. The dataset is [here](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/covertype/covertype.html), though it is quite large (apologies). If a base dataset comes to mind, please let me know and I'll gladly update to make more reproducible. Any thoughts are greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: `var <- factor(var)` and then return `var` after setting the levels.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things in life... Thank you, that works perfectly! If you reply with that as an answer I'm happy to mark it correct / accept it.

Comment: Or use a function that has already been optimized for you `df$var <- as.factor( with(tidyr::gather(df), key[value == 1]) )`

Comment: @PierreLafortune I should have specified in the question that I strongly wanted to do this in {base}, but thank you for sharing another solution